# How is the execution order of docker run command' options (such as "-v" )?Which first execute?

Tags: docker, volumes

I want to run a docker with mounting a host directory. The command is like this "docker run -it -v /hostdata:/data /bin/echo hello world". So, I'd like to know the sequence of option "-v /hostdata:/data " and "/bin/echo hello" command. That docker command will execute "/bin/echo hello" firstly? Or execute "-v /hostdata:/data" firstly? Please ignore my English grammar.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounts are first, then the container is "booted" and the docker CMD / ENTRYPOINT commands are run